# changing image src onClick without using attr

Tags: javascript

Is there something wrong with this code? I am trying to do the simple action of changing the src of an img named "midimg" upon mouse-click. It's not working and i don't know why

```
<script type="javascript">
function buttonInCompany()
{
$('#desc').load('incompany.html');
document.images["midimg"].src="http://cageme.herokuapp.com/css/mrcage.jpg";
}

</script>

<div onClick="buttonInCompany()">Everything is cage's cage.<br><br></div>

<img name="midimg" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-BdfyYy_Y0gY/UP_3y3F2RDI/AAAAAAAAC-Q/eHPCltO8bG8/s1600/TomEngelsnicolas+thing.jpg">
```

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Do you get any errors?

Comment: What does not work? Any error messages? Run your script with a JS console open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the jQuery line? I just dropped it, than it [works as expected](http://tinkerbin.com/qC427Q9B).

```
function buttonInCompany()
{
    document.images["midimg"].src="http://cageme.herokuapp.com/css/mrcage.jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how you are apparently already using a js framework (I assume jQuery), why not do it a more proper way to begin with?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function buttonInCompany()
{
  $('#desc').load('incompany.html');
  $('#midimg').attr("src","http://cageme.herokuapp.com/css/mrcage.jpg");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#someID").click(function() {
     buttonInCompany();
  });  
});
</script>

<div id='someID'>Everything is cage's cage.<br><br></div>

<img id="midimg" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-BdfyYy_Y0gY/UP_3y3F2RDI/AAAAAAAAC-Q/eHPCltO8bG8/s1600/TomEngelsnicolas+thing.jpg">
```